# Stream Analytics Function Output Unable to Connect

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-stream-analytics

For some reason, I'm unable to make the connection from Stream Analytics to my Azure Function as an output. I have this exact pipeline set up and working in my own Azure subscription, but can't get this output connection to work in my dev environment.

[Unable to load subscriptions PIC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5Shs.png)

First, the drop-down does not load the available function apps and functions in the subscription, as seen above. There are multiple that are in the subscription and are running, so this should populate. Instead, I see the error "Failed to load function apps" and "Failed to load functions."

Second, when I try to fill in the fields manually (after selecting "Provide azure function settings manually") I am also unable to connect. To do this, I'm giving the output a unique name, then copy/pasting the function app name and function name to the blanks. For the key, I've tried many variations to no avail. My function currently has Authorization set to anonymous, and I've tried leaving the key field blank. I've also tried using the "Function" key on my function, as well as the _master and default access keys. Each give me an error message when testing output connection. How do I get this connected?

[Manual function setup PIC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PpZd.png)

Here is the error that I get

[Error PIC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bl8Ly.png)

UPDATE - I'm still working on this, but at least part of it was due to having a hyphen "-" in the function name. Apparently Azure doesn't like that. Once I fixed the function name I'm able to trigger the function manually from within the Azure portal and externally through Postman, but still the connection test is failing from Stream Analytics.

UPDATE 2 - My temporary work around has been to have Stream Analytics post its output to an Event Hub, and trigger a function off of the Event Hub's traffic.

Comment: Please consider including the images you link to in the actual post, inline. Also, don't use comments to update the content of the post; edit the post itself and update the content accordingly.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have enough Stack Overflow points to include the images inline :(, but, I'll be sure to include updates to the body. Thanks!